# Get all URLs from plain CSS

Tags: php, regex

Let's say we have some CSS in our `$plain_css` variable:

```
.slide-pause {
  cursor: url(http://example.com/img/bg/pause.png),url(http://example.com/img/bg/pause.png),auto;
}
.something {
  background-image: url('http://example.com/img/bg/beautiful.png'); // We have Quotes here
}
```

I need to get all URLs from this CSS.

This is how I'm trying to achieve this:

```
preg_match_all('!url\(\'?http://example.com/.*\)!', $plain_css, $matches);
```

What `$matches` returns:

```
array
  0 => 
  array
    0 => string 'url(http://example.com/img/bg/pause.png),url(http://localhost/site/img/bg/pause.png)'
    1 => string 'url(http://example.com/img/bg/beautiful.png)'
```

What I need it to return:

```
array
  0 => string 'url(http://example.com/img/bg/pause.png)'
  1 => string 'url(http://example.com/img/bg/pause.png)'
  2 => string 'url(http://example.com/img/bg/beautiful.png)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're a victim of [greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy). `.*` matches as much as it can. Replace it with `.*?` to make it ungreedy for a quick fix. Or disallow `)` from the repeated characters (which is usually preferred - it's more explicit and more efficient):

```
preg_match_all('!url\(\'?http://example.com/[^)]*)!', $plain_css, $matches);
```

Note that you can't convince `preg_match_all` to return everything in a plain array - you will always get a nested array (which is important for [capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)). But you can simply get your desired result from `$matches[0]`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, nice note also about capturing, didn't knew that!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your repetition quantifier lazy (the default is greedy):

```
preg_match_all('!url\(\'?http://example.com/.*?\)!', $plain_css, $matches);
```

The only change here is that I added a question mark after the `*` repetition quantifier.  Normally, repetitions are *greedy*: that is, they match as many characters as they possibly can (and still satisfy the expression).  In this case, the greediness of the `*` quantifier was consuming both `url` expressions in your input string.  Changing to a lazy quantifier fixes the problem.

The other way to handle this is to use a negated character class instead of the `.` metacharacter (which matches any character except a newline):

```
preg_match_all('!url\(\'?http://example.com/[^)]*\)!', $plain_css, $matches);
```